winctl.node was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 89
Node.js Version: 16.18.1 (ABI => 93)
Electron.js Version: 14.0.1(ABI => 89)
I have an electron.js project, I want to implement functionality to track active window whenver it changes. for this functionality I found a way to use native C++ code and build it using node-gyp
Here's error I'm getting when I use winctl module.
App threw an error during load
Error: The module '\\?\F:\GC Download\Time Tracker\CTT Local\tmp\timetracker-electron\src\WindowTracker\build\Release\winctl.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 89. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1846)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1846)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:940:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:781:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12913)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:964:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at bindings (F:\GC Download\Time Tracker\CTT Local\tmp\timetracker-electron\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\GC Download\Time Tracker\CTT Local\tmp\timetracker-electron\src\WindowTracker\windowTrackerHelpers\index.js:5:16)

Here's my package.json file:
{
  "name": "crest-tracker-hari",
  "version": "1.3.2",
  "description": "time tracking app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "electron .",
    "dev": "npx electronmon .",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Crest Infosystems Pvt Ltd",
  "license": "ISC",
  "build": {
    "appId": "tms.crestinfosystems1.net",
    "productName": "CrestTracker1",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "publish": [
        {
          "provider": "generic",
          "url": "https://tms.crestinfosystems.net/api/app/download"
        }
      ]
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": false
    },
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bindings": "^1.2.1",
    "croner": "^6.0.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "electron-log": "^4.4.8",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-updater": "^6.1.4",
    "electronmon": "^2.0.2",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "node-addon-api": "^7.0.0",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
    "node-gyp": "^9.4.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.6",
    "systeminformation": "^5.18.9",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.2.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.2.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.2.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.2.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.2.1",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^6.2.1",
    "electron": "^14.0.1",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.4",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.9",
    "nan": "^2.15.0"
  }
}

I have used this native code provided here: https://github.com/davenonymous/winctl
Additionally I tried different Electron.js Versions that could match ABI version of 93 (Node V16.18.1)
tested electron 18.0.0 against node 16.18.1-> 109 (these are ABI versions of electron.js this side)
tested electron 15.0.0 against node 16.18.1 -> 98
tested electron 12.0.0 against node 16.18.1 -> 87
tested electron 13.0.0 against node 16.18.1 -> 89
tested electron 14.0.0 against node 16.18.1 -> 89
tested electron 14.2.8 against node 16.18.1 -> 97
tested electron 14.1.1 against node 16.18.1 -> 97
tested electron 14.0.2 against node 16.18.1 -> 97
tested electron 14.0.0-beta.5 against node 16.18.1 -> 89
tested electron 14.0.0-beta.25 against node 16.18.1 -> 89
tested electron 14.0.1 against node 16.18.1 -> 89

I tried these commands whenever I change electron.js version
rmdir /Q/S node_module
npm cache clear -f
npm i electron@Version -D
npm i
npm rebuild winctl --update-binary
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd   or npx electron-rebuild
npm run start

I have tried almost all similar stackoverflow solutions such as these:
Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51
compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67
So please don't suggest anyof these links to try
